# Open Tab Pane regarding Url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, getelementsbytagname, pane

Different topics are covered on the individual tabs. On the one are shown pictures on the next the menu card, etc..

I would now like to be able to select a specific tab with the url.

Example:
https://example.com/mypage -> Opens the page and the first tab.

https://example.com/mypage/tab2 -> Opens the page and the second tab.

or
https://example.com/mypage#tab2 -> Opens the page and the second tab.

This is my current code that I would like to modify:

```js
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

function openPane(evt, paneName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabpane, tablink;
  
    // Get all elements with class="tabpane" and hide them
    tabpane = document.getElementsByClassName("tabpane");
    for (i = 0; i < tabpane.length; i++) {
      tabpane[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
    // Get all elements with class="s" and remove the class "active"
    tablink = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
      tablink[i].className = tablink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
  
    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(paneName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
```

```css
/* --- TABS HEADER & WRAPPER START --- */

.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

/* --- profile tab wrapper --- */

.profile-tab-wrapper {
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999999999;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* --- tab link --- */

.tablink {
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: none;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}

.tablink.active {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #101010;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* --- TABS HEADER & WRAPPER END --- */
/* --- TABS CONTENT WRAPPER START --- */

.content-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* --- TABS CONTENT WRAPPER END --- */
/* --- TABS DISPLAY ON/OFF START --- */

.tabpane {
  display: none;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

/* --- TABS DISPLAY ON/OFF END --- */
/* --- LINKS TAB START --- */

/* --- titel --- */

.titel-wrapper {
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.8);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.titel {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* --- button --- */

.button-wrapper {
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999999;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.8);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #101010;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #101010;
  outline-color: #101010;
  outline-offset: 0px;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear, background-color 800ms cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);
  transition: color 200ms linear, background-color 800ms cubic-bezier(.23, 1, .32, 1);
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0);
  color: #101010;
}

/* --- LINKS TAB END --- */
/* --- ABOUT TAB START --- */

.about-left {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.about-center {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.about-right {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.about-titel {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
}

.about-text {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* --- ABOUT TAB END --- */
/* --- NO CONTENT START --- */

.nocontent-header {
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nocontent-subhead {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* --- NO CONTENT END --- */
```

```html
<div class="tabs">

        <div class="profile-tab-wrapper">

          <button class="tablink active" onclick="openPane(event, 'Links')" id="defaultOpen">LINKS</button>

          <button class="tablink" onclick="openPane(event, 'Images')">IMAGES</button>


          <button class="tablink" onclick="openPane(event, 'About')">ABOUT</button>

        </div>


        <div class="tabs-content">
          
          <div id="Links" class="tabpane">
            <div class="content-wrapper">

              <div class="titel-wrapper">
                <div class="titel">Titel 1</div> <!-- Insert Titel -->
              </div>

              <div class="button-wrapper">
                <a class="button" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
                  <div>Link 1</div>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="Images" class="tabpane">
            <div class="content-wrapper">

              <div class="nocontent-header">There are no images yet</div>
              <div class="nocontent-subhead">When something is uploaded, you will see it here.</div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="About" class="tabpane">
            <div class="content-wrapper">

              <div class="about-center">
                <div class="about-titel">This is a titel</div>
                <div class="about-text">This is some text</div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

How to implement this with a domain extension?

Comment: Opens what page and what tab? Can you include some more JavaScript and context? I'm having a hard time understanding. What did you mean by domain extension? TLD? Browser Extension?

Comment: I have modified my question a little bit and I also added some of the code.
I hope that helps and you can help me with my question.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand your question better. One question: since you want a user to visit yoursite.com/mypage/tab2, It'd be helpful to know what server you're using. (If you don't know details you know might be helpful, like if you're using live server on VSCode, shared hosting, Caddy, or whatever.)

Comment: I'm using the service of IONOS. Therefore it's shared hosting - correct?

Comment: Oh, it's probably (very likely) Apache. Let's forget about that first though, as it's not very important.

Comment: Okay is it possible thought?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment.

Comment: Of course thanks

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't write an answer because I don't have a lot of time. You can use `window.location.hash = "whateverhash"` to change the current URL hash and check `window.location.hash` to get it. Get it?

Comment: Great!! I wrote a very long answer and accidentally deleted it, so I just resorted to writing a comment :)